# Change width of Drawer in Android by weight?

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I have this Design, with a drawer inside:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".Main" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I want to change the width of drawer by setting weights, how to do it with this example? I want the width of drawer takes always 1/2 of the visible screen width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do this programmatically in your code.  You will need the display width and height and then you can modify the width of your linear layout above.  You get the height and width with the following:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
displayViewWidth_ = size.x;
displayViewHeight_ = size.y;
```

Then you can assign your layout a new width within your code based on this calculation such as with the following:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = drawer.getLayoutParams()
params.width = displayViewWidth_ / 2;
drawer.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: haha, currently I am doing that - but my wish was to solve that problem with weights - still dont know why it does not work with weights :S

Comment: I don't that you would be able to with just weights.  The second layout defines your drawer, and it is always a sub-class of your `DrawerLayout` class.  Weights will only work within `LinearLayout`.  So you should be able to provide a weight to the children inside the drawer, but not the drawer itself with regards to the screen.

Comment: how can I change width of  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
- of the linearlayout element programmatically?